# Display none is not working in media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, display

I am building a React App and I have in project two headers, one for desktop viewports and one for mobile. I set the one for desktop to disappear when user is on a mobile device (`display: none`).

The strangest thing is that when I enter from my phone and take a look on the DOM the desktop-header is still there

I double checked and the media query is the last one in every CSS file and could not be overwritten.

This is the site, if you want to check:

[acs-sporting.alinpeter.repl.co/](https://acs-sporting.alinpeter.repl.co/)

And here is my `css` in `index.scss` and `header-footer.scss`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
    display: none
  }
}
```

And as you may expect the `header` props are set before the `media` query.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could You please provide link to the repo or all Your code ?

Comment: this might not actually be the problem it appears to be, I just checked and this is working for me, is it possible that there is a cached css file on your phone and therefore the change is not actually showing up as you expect? you can either clear your browser cache, or just ask someone else to check on their phone. if that is the issue i would have a look into some sort of cachebusting method to ensure you can invalidate the cache when something changes

Comment: @ChrisWarnes I just checked from my friend's phone and is still not working. Open the menu and go to `Parteneri` page and click on the text before the cards section. It redirects you on an instagram page and that's because it is like the header just has `opacity: 0`, not `display: none`.

Comment: @MarioG8 I am doing this on replit.com
https://replit.com/@alinpeter/acs-sporting